# OpenLayers: How to shift zoom level content for ol/sourceXYZ about one zoom level

Tags: openlayers, zoom, dpi

The Swisstopo WMTS service assigns specific raster map content to specific zoom levels:

- ....
- 16: 1:25'000 Raster map
- 15: 1:50'000 Raster map
- 14: 1:100'000 Raster map
- ....

Here is a [code example](https://codepen.io/geoadmin/pen/pyzwwL?editors=0010).

Compared to other map source the result is an extremely inflated map content. Just compare the font size of text contained in these maps: [Swisstopo](https://www.skitourenguru.ch/track-view?area=ch&id=251) to [IGN](https://www.skitourenguru.ch/track-view?area=fr&id=333).

**How can I load the Swisstopo ol/sourceXYZ by shifting the content about one zoom level?** The result would be then:

- ....
- 17: 1:25'000
- 16: 1:50'000
- 15: 1:100'000
- ....

Comment: Please edit your question and include relevant code in the body of the question. Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swisstopo provides maps with different scales:

- [https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe-pk25.noscale/default/current/3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg](https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe-pk25.noscale/default/current/3857/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.jpeg)
- [https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe-pk50.noscale/default/current/3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg](https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe-pk50.noscale/default/current/3857/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.jpeg)
- [https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe-pk100.noscale/default/current/3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg](https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe-pk100.noscale/default/current/3857/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.jpeg)
- [https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe-pk200.noscale/default/current/3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg](https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe-pk200.noscale/default/current/3857/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.jpeg)
- [https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe-pk500.noscale/default/current/3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg](https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe-pk500.noscale/default/current/3857/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.jpeg)

You can group these maps to one common map. For each layer you are free to select any minZoom and maxZoom.
This solution has the advantage that it loads faster (no quadrupling of traffic).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change the fixed content of what is served, but you could set up OpenLayers to treat the 256 pixel tiles served as if they were hidpi 128 pixel tiles

```
  url: 'https://wmts10.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/' + layername + '/default/' + timestamp + '/3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg',
  tileSize: 128,
  tilePixelRatio: 2
```

The zoom level requested for any view resolution would then be offset by 1 (but you would be requesting 4 times as many tiles) https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/NWdZELE?editors=0010